# SQL Server : TRY/CATCH for ALTER TABLE - (add column) doesn't work

Tags: sql-server

I was expecting to get information that the column was not added, but instead of that I get the error. Why does try/catch not work in that case?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table

SELECT 1 AS FirstColumn INTO #Table

BEGIN TRY  
    ALTER TABLE #Table 
        ADD FirstColumn int;
    PRINT 'The column was added correctly'
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH       
    PRINT 'The column was not added, maybe it already exists?'
END CATCH
```

Comment: `TRY... CATCH` does not work on compilation errors, as it is never entered.

Comment: In general, if you find yourself doing this sort of dynamic table building on a temp table, strongly consider rethinking your approach. That way lies pain and madness -- T-SQL *really* wants table structures to be static, and you practically need to move to fully dynamic SQL for everything if you move away from that.

Comment: SQL, the language, is statically typed but the types are the tables and columns, not `int` or `varchar`. That's why table and columns can't be parameters, or why you can't have arbitrary columns in a `SELECT` clause. Even `SELECT *` gets expanded to the actual columns. Each data definition or manipulation statement in your script will get compiled separately and create an execution plan. In this case, `ALTER TABLE #Table ADD FirstColumn int;` fails to compile entirely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: although I know what you mean when you say that "tables [...] can't be parameters", this statement is still needlessly confusing given that table-valued parameters are a thing *and* that T-SQL permits identifiers to be passed unquoted to stored procedures (`sp_rename oldtable, newtable`). I wouldn't complicate manners by saying tables are types; it's not literally true in T-SQL and in relational algebra it's more accurate to speak of relations and tuple sets (and there's technically no requirement there that those come from statically defined tables).

Comment: I'm not sure what either of those statements are trying to state, @BogdanSahlean . Can you please try to reword.

Comment: if you wrap your alter code into a EXEC('alter table ...') it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamic add column and you are not sure if column exists.
This should work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table

SELECT 1 AS FirstColumn INTO #Table


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'FirstColumn'
          AND Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table'))
BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #Table 
        ADD FirstColumn int;
END
```